# Why Pipenv Locking Failed?

Tags: pip, virtualenv, pipenv

Why is pipenv unable to lock Pipfile.lock?

```
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
✘ Locking Failed!
```

chmod 777 does not solve the issue.